# Hadoop services are still running without "starting" services in Cloudera Manager

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

How Cloudera designed the Cloudera manager?

Because without starting the Hadoop services, the Hadoop daemons are running fine in the background.

Comment: What is your question here? The manager seems to be closed source, so no one here can know. I'm guessing they simply start the services if needed? Why even bother?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what issues you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudera Manager is just a web app that is collecting data from external agents.

The **Cloudera Manager Agent** runs as a side-car process on every node and allows for RPC actions (start, stop, reconfigure, etc.) between the Manager UI and the processes that are being monitored on each remote machine (HDFS, YARN, Hive, Spark, etc).

See [How does Cloudera Manager Work](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/07/how-does-cloudera-manager-work/)

This is similar to how Apache Ambari operates, which is open-source, and uses EmberJS, Python, and SSH for its operations.